# How to Get Current Window height & width after change Orientation in React-Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I used Dimensions class for get Current Window Width & Height. its Proper works when first time lunch screen buts its now working with change Orientation.**(Not Height-Width get When Change Orientation)**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Dimensions
} from 'react-native';

const window = Dimensions.get('window');

let aspectRatio = window.Width / window.Height;

export default class Home extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 22}}>Height is {aspectRatio}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }// end of render
};
```

Answer (score 9):

RN gave you an event listener that you can use whenever a property within the **Dimensions** object changes. You can read about it more [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html#addeventlistener).

The event will output an object that has the screen dimensions info and the window. You can then simply update the state whenever an orientation occurs.

```
Dimensions.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const { width, height } = e.window;
  this.setState({width, height});
})
```